# symfony4: start and track progress of long background task

Tags: shell, symfony, symfony4

I have a symfony4 application that has a backend processing component that takes several minutes to run. At the moment, it is started with a bash script and a few symfony console commands.

I'd like to be able to start this process in the web-interface, and have its progress displayed (and prevent that it is started again while still running).

The background task doesn't need to take any parameters, it reads all data it needs from the database.

Since the backend process takes long, I don't want to have a webpage hang around while it runs. The web-frontend needs to start it and then detach. The user is intended to come back later to check the results.

I couldn't find a solution in the Symfony documentation or on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) for long background tasks.

You can alternatively handle long tasks by subscribing to the [PostResponseEvent](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-terminate) but that only works if you are not using modphp.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just in case, you can wrap words into links to achieve better reading experience.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution which I see is to have a table "transaction" with a unique id - once the background task is triggered you create a transaction first and set a flag to "running" (and of course to done or even delete it when done).

When you return this id to the requester of the background task it can easily ask for this transaction id and its status when you want to see an update.

Comment: yes, but how do I create that background task from Symfony ?

Comment: what's wrong with starting a bash script / symfony command from your app? this should be non-blocking, right?

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to do that. Process? execute? system call? Is there a Symfony way?

Comment: sorry, probably don't get your question then. how should i know what's the best way to trigger your processes not knowing anything about it? does it need to be cross-OS compatible? are there specific IO, DB etc. permissions? are there any DB locks to be considered? if it's "just" simple database maintenance without any concurrency issues, why not using your current symfony command and starting it from your app? but I suggest to give more details about what you really want to achieve plus details.